# Approximating the value of pi in C using Viete's Formula

Tags: c, while-loop, pi

My assignment this week in my CS class is create a program to approximate for pi using Viète's Formula. I've been trying to start for the past hour or so, but I'm honestly not even sure how to begin. All the work I have gotten done doesn't work.

I'm assuming my professor wants us to use the "while" loop, as we've been using it a lot in class lately. We've also been using "if" statements a lot, although I'm not sure if we need to use those here.

Can anyone help me find a starting off point or explain how I could go about doing this?

```
//here is some of the work i have attempted that doesn't work because i don't know what to do
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <math.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main() 

{ 
double n,pi,f,i; 

printf("enter the number of iterations to approximate for pi\n"); 
scanf("%lf\n", &n); 

pi = 2 / f; 
i = 1; 
f = sqrt(2);

while (i<=n)
{ 



}
```

Comment: "All the work I have gotten done doesn't work." - please post this.

Comment: @Amadan i have added the edit

Comment: Of course it doesn't work - it is unfinished. Are you using `while` because the professor has been talking about `while` a lot, or because you understand that there is something to repeat in the problem? If so, what do you think is it? What do you think should be the purpose of `i`, and how does it change? `pi = 2 / f`, you say - but you don't define `f` until later, so that can't possibly work (the statements are correct, but the order is wrong).

Comment: Yeah, it's unfinished because I wasn't sure what else to do with it. I'm using `while` because I need a way to add the next iteration up to the desired number. The `sqrt(2)` is repeated throughout the formula. I was thinking `i` would be used as a counter. I had `f = sqrt(2)`, but because the formula required multiple `sqrt(2)` to be added, I'm not sure if that's entirely correct? @Amadan

Comment: It is correct (just raise `f = sqrt(2)` above `pi = 2 / f`). Thinking of `i` as a counter is fine; but then it needs to _count_. So incrementing `i`, at least, should be inside the loop. What else? You'll probably want to multiply `pi` with something. What will it be? [Wikipedia tells you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formula#Interpretation_and_convergence) how to get `a[i]` from `a[i - 1]`. This might lead you to change your initial definition of `pi`. Also, if `n` is a number of iterations and `i` just counts, should they be `double`, or something else?

Comment: Read also https://www.floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with the code you posted:

1) You don't want `i` and `n` to be of type `double` Change them to `int`

2) You should always check the value returned by `scanf` Like: `if (scanf(%d) != 1) {// add error handling here ...}`

3) `pi = 2 / f;` is undefined behavior as `f` is uninitialized

Then your assignment:

I'll not give you a complete solution but instead give you a hint so you can continue your work.

The formula needed can be found here: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viète%27s_formula#Interpretation_and_convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formula#Interpretation_and_convergence)

Your first task is to calculate `a[n]` given that

```
a[1] = sqrt(2)
a[n] = sqrt(2 + a[n-1])
```

You can do that using a while-loop (though I would prefer a for-loop). It could be like:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <math.h> 

int main() 
{ 
    int n, i;
    n = 5;
    i = 1;
    double an = sqrt(2);

    while(i <= n)
    {
        printf("a%d = %.10f\n", i, an); 
        an = sqrt(2 + an);
        ++i;
    }
    return 0;    
}
```

This gives you:

```
a1 = 1.4142135624
a2 = 1.9615705608
a3 = 1.9975909124
a4 = 1.9998494037
a5 = 1.9999905876
```

So now that you know how to calculate a1, a2, a3, ... you just need to put it together using:

[image]

(image from: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viète%27s_formula#Interpretation_and_convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formula#Interpretation_and_convergence))

and find pi.